# VGA 15P D-Sub --> 2 row motherboard socket

Tags: vga

I have a SuperMicro X9DRW-iF motherboard, whose female VGA video connector literally broke off the motherboard whilst I was pushing the video cable into the connector. OK, no worries -- I thought,  I took out the motherboard in hopes of just buying a replacement right-angle VGA DB15 connector for soldering into the motherboard.

Well, to my surprise, the motherboard pin layout for the VGA connector (the holes that would accept the male pins from the VGA socket), are not laid out in a standard 3-row pattern...but instead in a 2 row pattern:

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have searched high and low on trying to find a female VGA 15 pin socket (right-angle) whose pins that solder to the motherboard are in 2 rows. I also tried searching for a a LAPTOP VGA female socket...but I couldn't find one that accepts 2 rows of pins for soldering. I am confused.

EDIT:  The connector looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know what kind of 2-row VGA socket this SuperMicro motherboard has?

Comment: Have you investigated an adapter cable?

Comment: Look for "VGA to ribbon" or "VGA to IDC 16 pin". This is a common adapter.

Comment: I did search that...but the motherboard-size has 2-rows, 15 pins (not 16 pins). I found an image of an Antenk "slim VGA 15P right-angle" connector", which looks like the right part, but doesn't seem to be able to purchase one from Antenek directly...

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

Datasheet: http://www.e-tec.com/v5/documents/pdfs/d-sub-and-i-o-connectors/DS-06_10.pdf

Product page: https://www.e-tec.com/v5/products/d-sub-and-i-o-connectors/d-sub-ultra-slim-profile/d-sub-ultra-slim-profile-90deg-tht/d-sub-ultra-slim-15-pin-female-high-density-tht-90deg_10.html

Found this as well, but it seems a little bit more shady: https://www.elecbee.com/en-5489-slim-d-sub-15f-d-sub-vga-15-pin-female-right-angle-though-hole-connector-

I'll do some more searching. Perhaps there is something on mouser or digikey

Answer (score 0):

It is a slim VGA 15P right-angle connector.

** Link removed due to wrong part **

**EDIT:**  Well, that's not it...despite Mouser listing it as a "2 rows" soldering side.

Comment: From the datasheet: "Number of Rows      3"

Comment: @OskarSkog I wouldn't read too much into that, it does say "number of rows 3" but it doesn't say whether that is on the solder side or the mating side. Unfortunately Molex don't seem to offer a drawing of the part, so I suspect the only way to find out for sure is to order one.